# how to properly get plucked name by going through multiple tables and compare it to a string?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am still am not familiar with laravel and I want to get the 'name' of the Organization that the $user is joined. I have 3 tables: Users, Organizations and Organization_users with their respective models User, Organization, and OrganizationUser.

The logic that I want to implement is: get the uuid of the currently logged in user and find the user_id in OrganizationUser which is a foreign key of the uuid in the Users table. After that, I want to find which organization the user is in by using the OrganizationUsers table in which the Organization's primary uuid is a foreign key to the OrganizationUser's organization_id then pluck the name and then compare it to a string.

here is my code.

```
    $user   = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    $org_user_profile = OrganizationUser::where('user_id',$user->uuid)->get();
    $profile_org_relation = Organization::where('uuid',$org_user_profile->organization_id)->pluck('name');

    if ($profile_org_relation == "Org1") {
#condition here
```

It works until the $org_user_profile line and it sends an error

> Property [organization_id] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Mention the exact Laravel version.

Comment: @Gabriel it's Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this line

> $org_user_profile =
>   OrganizationUser::where('user_id',$user->uuid)->get();

When using get() function, you need to use loop to see the data. You should use first() instead to retrieve single row/column from a table. With first() you can get your data like this

> $org_user_profile->organization_id

So, you should modify your code as:

```
$org_user_profile = OrganizationUser::where('user_id',$user->uuid)->first();
$profile_org_relation = Organization::where('uuid',$org_user_profile->organization_id)->pluck('name');
```

[Laravel 5.5 - Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results)